# monaca、iPhoneで動画のインライン再生はできますでしょうか

Tags: ios, monaca

Youtubeアプリのようなインライン再生がしたいのですが、可能でしょうか。

何も考えずにvideoタグを設置すると、HTMLブラウザ同様、全画面再生となります。

Comment: hataさん、返信ありがとうございます！
自己解決しました！

config.xmlと属性足したらできました！

Comment: 自己解決した場合は自分で解決した内容の解答を行い、その解答を自身で承認してください。そうすると他の同じ問題を抱えている人の助けにもなります。

Answer (score 1):

config.xmlファイル

AllowInlineMediaPlayback(ブール値、既定値は false )をtrue に変更すれば可能です。

参考：https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ja/3.1.0/guide/platforms/ios/config.html

Answer (score -3):

iframeかAVPlayerで表示されば可能だとおもいます。